# Orphaned Artifact iMessage Extension - iOS Bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, imessage, imessage-extension

I have added an embedded iMessage extension to my app like so:

[image]

[image]

When I update my app via TestFlight or the App Store my iMessage extension is installed without uninstalling the old causing the iMessage Extension to become completely unusable:

[image]

**"`Messages Extension Plugin`"**

If I touch the switch of `Messages Extension Plugin`, two switches turn off and on because they have the same identifier or reference on the list. My app and `"Messages Extension Plugin"`

You can reproduce this error in a similar way by [installing the Delta app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/fly-delta/id388491656#?platform=messages) that has an embedded iMessage Extension. Then delete the Delta app and reinstall, you will see an orphaned `Messages Extension Plugin` artifact.

Answer (score 1):

Not a developer here, but as a user, this is a bug I've dealt with for years on multiple phones, with multiple apps. Once an app updates if I want the image to show up in the iMessage share bar I have to:

1. Remove it from the share bar
2. Uninstall the app
3. Reinstall the app
4. Add it back to the share bar

Even this only has an 80% success rate (estimating obviously). I'm glad to hear some developers are reporting it as a bug, maybe it will finally get fixed. Reinstalling a couple of apps each time they update is very much a first-world problem, but annoying nonetheless.